# Java - Possible to pipe PrintWriter to InputStream/Reader?

Tags: java

I want to pipe JSP PrintWriter out to another support class that takes InputStream or Writer as argument.  I wonder if it's possible to simplify the process.

Of course I can write the output to a file, then use InputStream to read that file.

Comment: Yes, this can be done. I can't remember the details on this since it's been a while since I handled this, but you will likely need to consider threading issues. Perhaps using a producer/consumer queue would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

The "other" end of the JSP-provided `PrintWriter` is connected to the client (through the network, of course). You could create a new `PrintWriter`, pipe that to the support class and have the support class' output written to the original JSP `PrintWriter`.